# Rendering coure sql statement to linq equivalent

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Can anyone help me convert my sql statement yo linq query
Sql query:

```
select
       MIN(a.StockCode) AS StockCode,
       MIN(a.Qty) AS Qty,
       MIN(a.TotalAmt) AS TotalAmt,
       MIN(a.DateAlloted)AS DateAlloted,
       MIN(a.Buy_Sold_Ind) AS Buy_Sold_Ind,
       convert(bit, min(convert(int, a.Posted))) AS Posted,
       convert(bit, min(convert(int, a.Reversed))) AS Reversed,   
       MIN(a.CustAID) AS CustAID 
from Stkb_Sold a
group by a.StockCode
order by count(a.StockCode) DESC
```

Comment: Can you properly code highlight your SQL query ?

Comment: How in the world could we answer this question without knowing the model?  (of Posted and Reversed mostly)

Comment: Why are you grouping by `StockCode`, but then selecting `Min(StockCode)`?

Comment: @juharr - you don't want to get one that is to big.

Comment: Pls help me convert the above linq to sql. Thanks.

Comment: If `Posted` and `Reversed` are of type `bit` to begin with then you don't need to convert them to `int` and then back to `bit`.

Comment: @juharr. I group with stockcode because there are many of its kind in that field. A stockcode can appear as many times as possible.

Comment: @user3611905 But then you select `Min(StockCode)` which basically just gives you the same if you selected `StockCode`.

Comment: @ juharr. The posted and reverse does not really matter when converting to linq. leave out posted and reversed out of the expected fields

Comment: @user3611905 Can you provide us with your model at the very least?

Comment: @ juharr. No need for conversion if its in linq form. I converted it because it was in sql form.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this.

```
var result = from s in db.Stkb_Sold
             group s by s.StockCode into grp
             orderby grp.Count() descending
             select new
             {
                 StockCode = grp.Key,
                 Qty = grp.Min(x => x.Qty),
                 TotalAmt= grp.Min(x => x.TotalAmt),,
                 DateAlloted= grp.Min(x => x.DateAlloted),,
                 Buy_Sold_Ind= grp.Min(x => x.Buy_Sold_Ind),
                 Posted = grp.Min(x => x.Posted),
                 Reversed = grp.Min(x => x.Reversed),
                 CustAID = grp.Min(a.CustAID)
             };
```